regexpatch and newtx collisions
I learned today that
\usepackage{mathptmx}

is obsolete and should be replaced by
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

The problem is, that my template is using
\usepackage{regexpatch}

to change the - delimiter to an active character by these commands:
\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}

I need to change - to an active character to be able to use the command \cline{i-j} in my tables.
But when I use newtx and regexpatch packages together, I get many errors from newtx and regexpatchcollisions:
regexpatch.sty: Chyba: 375: LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\xshowcmd' already defined. }

I tried not to use regexpatch package but then commands to change - to an active character don't work and I can't use \cline{i-j} command.
What commands/packages should I use to be able to use \cline{i-j} and get no collisions between packages?

Unfortunately, xpatch and regexpatch aren't compatible. On the other hand, newtx loads xpatch for no reason.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@xpatch.sty}{3000/12/12}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
x & y \\
\cmidrule{2-2}
a & b \\
\cline{2-2}
a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You might also avoid regexpatch with a (clumsier) redefinition of the relevant commands.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
%\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{...}
%\def\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{...}
\toks0=\expandafter{\@cline#1-#2\@nil}
\toks2=\expandafter{\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]{#3}{#4}}
\catcode`-=\active
\def\x{\@cline##1-##2\@nil}\edef\y{\the\toks0}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\x\expandafter{\y}
\def\x{\@@@cmidrule[##1-##2]##3##4}\edef\y{\the\toks2}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\x\expandafter{\y}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
x & y \\
\cmidrule{2-2}
a & b \\
\cline{2-2}
a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


thanks. And what exactly \ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@xpatch.sty}{3000/12/12} does?

@JanK It's a hack meant to trick LaTeX into thinking that a very recent version of xpatch has already been loaded. There is also a function for this in the LaTeX kernel, but I never remember how it's called.
